# Pfaffian properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pfaffian

Given a $2n\times 2n$ real skew-symmetric matrix $A$, its Pfaffian $\mathrm{Pf}$ is defined as:
$$
\mathrm{Pf}(A) = \frac1{2^n n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{2n}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n A_{\sigma(2i-1),\sigma(2i)}
$$
where $S_{2n}$ is the symmetric group, and $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ is the signature of the permutation $\sigma$.

I'm looking for general properties of Pfaffians, which go beyond the ones stated in its [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfaffian) entry. More specifically, I'd like to know general conditions for the equality between the Pfaffian of a convex sum, and the convex sum of Pfaffians. In plain math, let $A$ and $B$ be $2n\times 2n$ real skew-symmetric matrices, and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. What are the conditions for the equality
$$\mathrm{Pf}((1-\lambda)A +\lambda \;B) = (1-\lambda)\;\mathrm{Pf}(A) +\lambda\; \mathrm{Pf}(B)$$
 to hold?

A general reference on Pfaffians would also be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I found some literature on Pfaffian sums. Check for instance the series of three articles by M. Ishikawa, S. Okada and M. Wakayama entitled _Applications of Minor-Summation Formula_. The answer to the question I posed seems to not be explicitly given there, but the articles, specially the second [one](http://www.uec.tottori-u.ac.jp/~mi/papers/JofCTA88.pdf), contain all sort of properties about Pfaffians.

Comment: You might consider answering your own question with the update and accept it. (Completely for archive reasons ;)

Comment: @percusse I'll definitely do it, as soon as I get a more complete answer to the question. Up to now I only have special cases -- which are enough for my purposes, but not the whole thing...